# How to insert attributes into a WFS using OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

So I have a web app that's running and is able to add points and lines to existing Postgis tables by getting data from Geoserver. I need the following one specific bit of functionality added:

I want to allow users to also be able to add attribute information to each point on the map interface. As in, each point they draw on the map, there needs to be something that allows the user to also enter some text data to the column.

I've tried reading a few questions in here but none of them provide a solution for a point vector layer.

How to do this?

The bit I have for loading and posting the WFS point features is:

```
var vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
var url2 =    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BFTchambers:chamber2&' +
'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures2' +
'&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
$.ajax({url: url2, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false})
.done(function(response) {
    pointWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),
    sourceVector2.addFeatures(pointWFS.readFeatures(response))
    });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
maxZoom: 20
})),
});

window.loadFeatures2 = function(response) {
console.log("Point features were drawn");
vectorSource2.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
};
var formatWFS2 = new ol.format.WFS();
var pointGML = new ol.format.GML({
featureNS: 'http://geoserver.org/bftchamber',
featureType: 'chamber2',
});

var pointWFS = function(p,f) {
switch(p) {
case 'insert':
    node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction([f],null,null,pointGML);
    break;
case 'update':
    node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,pointGML);
    break;
case 'delete':
    node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],pointGML);
    break;
}
s = new XMLSerializer();
str = s.serializeToString(node);
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: str
    }).done();
    console.log(" point features were posted to server");
}
case 'btnDrawPoint':
    interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        type: 'Point',
        source: layerVector.getSource()
    });
    map.addInteraction(interaction);
    interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
        pointWFS('insert',e.feature);
    });
    break;
```

Comment: What does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved this with a Javascript prompt by using the following code:

```
 interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
//pass an attribute to the feature
var myAttrValue = prompt("Enter Attribute", "");
var myFeature= e.feature;
if (myAttrValue != null) {
 myFeature.set('column', myAttrValue);
 }

pointWFS('insert',myFeature);
});
```